# Pattern matching for list of pairs scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, tuples

I have been trying to learn pattern matching and pairs in Scala and use it to implement the merge sort but the pattern matching. But the pattern match to extract head and tail pair doesn't work. What is it which I am missing in the below code?

```
def merge(xs: List[Int], ys: List[Int]): List[Int] =
  (xs, ys) match {
    case (x: Int, y: Int) :: (xs1: List[Int], ys1: List[Int]) =>
      if (x < y) x :: merge(xs1, ys)
      else y :: merge(xs, ys1)
    case (x: List[Int], Nil) => x
    case (Nil, y: List[Int]) => y
  }
```

Comment: Also, please don't just say "doesn't work". Give error messages, details of unexpected result, whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a syntax error in your 1st case statement, change it to

```
case (x :: xs1 , y :: ys1)
```

from

```
case (x: Int, y: Int) :: (xs1: List[Int], ys1: List[Int])
```

You are trying to match a tuple containing Lists, not List of Tuples